# Reference function and "toggle" it

Tags: javascript

My current code:

```
window.onerror = function() {

    console.log('error', arguments);

    return false;
};
```

I would like to be able to bind and unbind the event whenever I want. Something like this:

```
var errorHandler = function() {

    console.log('error', arguments);

    return false;
};

var noop = function(){};

function toggleErrorHandler(enable){
    window.onerror = enable ? errorhandler : noop;
}
```

Is this the correct way to do it? My guess is that it's not :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems correct. A modification could be removing the use of `noop` function.

```
window.onerror = enable ? errorhandler : null ;
```

is enough to remove the handlers.

Comment: Ok, so I don't have to do an explcit "unbind" of the event? Or perhaps an unbind in Jquery for example == nullifying the function?